# Sound cannot be played

Tags: android, audio-player

I create a simple project with one layout that contains two buttons, and this is my code:

```
package com.example.tessound;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
    MediaPlayer player;
    Button play,mute;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        play = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        play.setOnClickListener(this);
        mute = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        mute.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        if(view.getId()==R.id.button1)
        {
            playSound(1);
        }
        else if(view.getId()==R.id.button2)
        {
            playSound(2);
        }
    }

    public void playSound(int arg)
    {
        if (arg == 1)
        {
            player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.atur);
        }
        else if (arg == 2)
        {
            player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.back);
        }

        if(player != null)
        {
            player.setLooping(false);
            player.start();
        }

        try
        {
            if(player != null)
            {
                if (player.isPlaying()) 
                {
                    player.stop();
                    player.release();
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

When I tried to click the button the sound doesn't play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the logic for your playSound method with an argument value of 1:

1) arg == 1 so:

```
player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.atur);
```

2) player has been set so is not null, hence:

```
player.setLooping(false);
player.start();
```

3) Then it's your try block. player is not null and is playing, hence:

```
player.stop();
player.release();
```

So I think you are starting the playback and then immediately stopping it. I imagine you should only execute the try/catch code if the method does not receive a valid argument, i.e. it should be an 'else' of the preceding 'if' statement.

EDIT:

Looking at this again, I think the try/catch code should go at the top of the method. It will then stop the player and release it (if it is in use) before trying to start playing a new sound. Logically that makes sense.

Comment: This looks like the right answer. I'd also use `SoundPool` instead of `MediaPlayer` personally

Comment: so i should put

    player.stop();
    player.release();

in else statement?

Comment: i have built another project, and few weeks ago i have used this code and there was no problem, but i didn't remember when the sound was not played anymore till now.. x_x

Comment: Seems like the right answer. There's also the possibility that for some reason the resources have been corrupted and the player is null on initialization. I'd add code to catch and alert with a Toast, for instance, if the player is null.  (look at the MediaPlayer reference here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create(android.content.Context, int) )

Comment: i have moved the try/catch to the top of the method, and this is working :D
my raw folder contains atur.mp3, back.mp3, belajar.mp3, level.mp3, skip.mp3, start.mp3... while i click button mute, back.mp3 is played, but when i click button play, all of the mp3 in raw folder is played x_x do you know why?

Comment: Sorry no, I can't explain that. Stack Overflow rules say we need to stay on the topic of the specific question raised. If this specific problem is now resolved, please close it off and feel free to raise a new question detailing this new issue you are experiencing. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Use Log to trace the control and find the error !

```
Log.e("AnyTAG","Description of the Log");
```

your code seems fine!

Comment: this just a code to trace the control in logCat ! paste it anywhere and you will get the output in the logCat ! This is used for Debugging !

I would suggest go through this tutorial it covers both the "LOG" thing and your sound tutorial ! http://javapapers.com/android/how-to-play-audio-in-android/